# Вызов метода компонента за пределами экземпляра Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В прототипе компонента, есть метод (функция). Как вызвать этот метод за пределами экземпляра Vue? Например, в теге `head`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За пределами компонента создаем кастомное событие и пишем код, по которому это событие должно сработать. Генерируем его на документе. В компоненте вешаем обработчик нашего кастомного события, в котором вызываем нужный метод. Наслаждаемся результатом)
Пример:

`index.html`

```
const event = new Event('hop');
   setTimeout(function(){
     document.dispatchEvent(event)
      },5000)
```

`Component.vue`

```
 created() {
    document.addEventListener('hop', this.handlerHop);
  },
  methods: {
    handlerHop(event) {
      console.log(event)
    }
  }
```

П.С.: как обычно, решение приходит после того, как задашь вопрос на SO.

Comment: Можно попросить выложить пример в фидле? Что то не соображу, как сделать)

Comment: @VOV, подправил ответ. Думаю так будет понятнее.