# Вызов модального окна vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть модальное окно на vue.js. Хочу внедрить его на сайт и по клику на кнопку вызывать. Возможно ли привязать вызов окна на vue к любой обычной кнопке на сайте?

Comment: да, возможно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893527/Вызов-метода-компонента-за-пределами-экземпляра-vue

Comment: @Дмытрык спасибо!